# How to test if a time series is a white noise in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, noise

How to test if a time series `x(t) (t=1,2...n)` is a white noise in Matlab?

`x(t)` does not have to be Gaussian. `kstest()` will not work. `autocorr(X)` only test auto-correlation; it does not show the mean at each t is zero.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

For white noise, the condition is not mean=0 at each `t`, it is the overall mean for the sequence.  The values at each `t` need to be independent and the overall mean needs to be zero.

In a given sequence of `x(t)` for different `t`, it does not make sense to talk about mean at each `t` (because there is only one value at each `t`)

Comment: Technically the values only need to be uncorrelated to be a white noise.

Answer (score 0):

You can use autocorr() to find out if the signal is white noise or not.
The autocorrelation of a continuous white noise signal has a strong peak (Dirac delta function) at t=0, and is 0 for all t unequal 0.

Given the assumption that you have a discrete signal I presume that the result of this finite, discrete series will look more like a Gaussian, but with increased signal length the autocorr() will resemble the dirac impulse more closely.

The other condition you referred to, the zero mean can be tested, but not infinitely precise since you only have a finite number of elements... but if Matlab gives you a mean fairly close to zero it is a strong indicator that you got a noise signal.

Also: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autocorrelation